# Updating K&R-style parametrs

Tags: c++, c

Are there any utilities (along the lines of unix indent) that will automatically reformat code using K&R-style c function parameters to modern (well, post-1989) style?

I'm working on a moderately large old scientific code, which is littered with declarations like:

```
int cylind_volumes(w, icomp)
    WindPtr w;
    int icomp;
{
    [...code...]
```

It seems like it should be doable, and would make it easier to maintain & further develop (and potentially update to C++ etc.). This must be a solved problem?

Comment: While an interesting question, this is off-topic on Stack Overflow. It might be worthwhile to see whether it would be on-topic at [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: Search the web for "pretty print c++"

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/1/protoize GNU protoize

Comment: This might be something that [clang-modernize](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-modernize.html) could do (if not yet, maybe you should bring this up to its developers). I know that the motivation for clang-modernize was for C++98 -> C++11 modernizations, but I don't see why it couldn't be broader in scope.